# How to align input, select and input in a html form field using bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

[image]

I am trying to achieve above on the webpage with this:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="select">
            <select>
                <option>January</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control"><input type="text" class="input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But am getting this:

[image]

Am using bulma columns and form controls. Can you please help me, I need to horizontally pack elements at various places if you have any other good way to achieve it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When using columns in bulma, you should know that all columns will be of equal width. See [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/):

> Each column will have an equal width, no matter the number of columns.

That is also the case in your case. The columns are equal in size. The content of the columns, however, is not equal. The `input` elements have `width:100%` whereas the select does not.

To fix it, simply add `width:100%` to the `select` and its `.select` container:

```
.select,
select{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you, will check it once.